# Why does localstorage multi-toggle state code work in jsfiddle but not on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In last question I had assistance to create a code to save the state of a fairly complex toggle state. When a radio button is selected a checkbox slides down, when that checkbox is selected another one slides down. The reverse also occurs. Much of the code I do not understand. The problem now is that it works perfectly in jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/ovysmutL/7/

However, it does not function on my webpage. When localstorage restores the state back to the webpage after a page refresh it automatically 'unchecks' the checkboxes about 2 seconds after load when they should have remained checked.

I totally stripped down my page to try to isolate this issue...the problem still exists. I read and tried all the similar stackoverflow problems eg( modified forms, added doc ready function,etc)...  but obviously none of them helped.

The code works prior to localstorage insertion. When page is refreshed localstorage restores the state back to the webpage but it automatically 'unchecks' the checkboxes about 2 seconds after load when they should have remained checked. Does ANYBODY know what is going on AND HOW TO FIX THIS? I truly appreciate the help.

```
   **HTML**

    <form class="form" id="form-a" method="post" autocomplete="on">
    <fieldset>
      <div>
        <p>
          <label class="yes_text">Yes</label>
          <span>
            <input type="radio" data-show="next-a" id="dog" name="answer_name" value="yes">
          </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>No</label>
          <span>
            <input type="radio" name="answer_name" value="no" checked>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="next-a" class="hidden">
      <div class="red">
        <div>
          <p>Include Red Dogs:</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>
            <label class="yes_text_include">select to include</label>
            <span>
              <input type="checkbox" data-show="next-b" id="cat" class="red" name="red_name" value="">
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="next-b" class="hidden">
        <div>
          <p>Include Green Dogs:</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>
            <label>select to include</label>
            <span>
              <input type="checkbox" name="green_name" class="cat" value="">
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>
            <label>select to include</label>
            <span>
              <input type="checkbox" name="blue_name" class="cat" value="">
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <form class="form" id="form-b" method="post" autocomplete="on">
    <fieldset>
      <div>
        <p>
          <label class="yes_text">Yes</label>
          <span>
            <input type="radio" data-show="next-a" id="dog" name="answer_name" value="yes">
          </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>No</label>
          <span>
            <input type="radio" name="answer_name" value="no" checked>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="next-a" class="hidden">
      <div class="red">
        <div>
          <p>Include Red Dogs:</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>
            <label class="yes_text_include">select to include</label>
            <span>
              <input type="checkbox" data-show="next-b" id="cat" class="red" name="red_name" value="">
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="next-b" class="hidden">
        <div>
          <p>Include Green Dogs:</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>
            <label>select to include</label>
            <span>
              <input type="checkbox" name="green_name" class="cat" value="">
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>



  **Javascript**

    class CheckForm {
  constructor(option) {
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll(`${option}`);
    forms.forEach(form => {
      const formname = form.id;
      this.formCheck(formname);
      this.checkChecked(formname);
    });
  }

  formCheck(formName) {
    const form = document.querySelector(`#${formName}`);
    form.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const { target: { type, value, id, dataset: { show } } } = e;

      switch (type) {
        case 'radio': {
          if (value === 'yes') {
            $(`#${formName}`).find(`#${show}`).show(200);
            this.saveToLocalstore(formName);
          } else {
            $(`#${formName} fieldset`).next().hide(200);
            document.querySelector(`#${formName}`).reset();
            localStorage.removeItem(formName);
            this.removeAllChecked(formName);
          }
          break;
        }
        case 'checkbox': {
          $(`#${formName}`).find(`#${show}`).toggle(200);
          this.saveToLocalstore(formName);
          if (id) {
            this.removeAllChecked(formName, id);
          }
          break;
        }
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  saveToLocalstore(formName) {
    let allInput = document.querySelectorAll(`#${formName} input`);
    let object = {};
    allInput.forEach(item => {
      object[item.name] = item.type === 'radio' ? true : item.checked;
    });

    localStorage.setItem(formName, JSON.stringify(object));
  }

  checkChecked(formName) {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(formName));
    if (data) {
      let i = 1;
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        const item = document.querySelector(`#${formName} input[name='${key}']`);
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (value) {
            item.click();
          }
        }, i * 1000);
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  removeAllChecked(formName, id) {
    if (id) {
      let allInput = document.querySelectorAll(`#${formName} .${id}`);
      allInput.forEach(item => {
        item.checked = false;
      });
    } else {
      const allHidden = document.querySelectorAll(`#${formName} .hidden`);
      allHidden.forEach(item => {
        item.removeAttribute('style', '');
      });
    }
  }

}

new CheckForm('.form');



 **CSS**

    .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: At first glance, I do not see you reading the localStorage when the page first loads. You need to detect the page loading or reloading, then read localStorage and set the state of the checkboxes.  For ease of reading, please split your javascript and html into two snippets.

Comment: Also remember to turn off all your privacy extensions, custom settings etc, because it's entirely possible that it's not your code, but your own browser configuration.

Comment: Hello Mike 'Pomax', Thanks for that tidbit. I think you are on to something. I disabled all the protections. Now chrome and opera work, however firefox only partially works. The second checkmark stays checked but it still unchecks the first checkbox. Do you know what is going on with this? Also do you know how to setup the script to get around this....so it works without the user removing all the securities in their browsers, since this will not happen in the real world?